# django Baseserializer remove certain fields from validated_data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-serializer, django-validation

I need to validate a payload json based on, say, fields A, B. But I don't want these to show in `serializer.validated_data`

I tried to override `validated_data` base class method.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    fieldA = ...
    fieldB = ...
    fieldC = ...
    def validate_fieldA(self, fieldA):
        # validate
    def validate_fieldB(self, fieldB):
        # validate
    def validated_data(self):
        data = super().validated_data()

        exclude_fields = self.context.get('exclude_fields', [])
        for field in exclude_fields:
            # providing a default prevents a KeyError
            # if the field does not exist
            data.pop(field, default=None)

        return data
```

Now when I try to access `serializer.validated_data` dict, it returns a method instead of deserialized dictionary.

```
<bound method MySerializer.validated_data of ....
```

How do I accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override "validate" method instead of "validated_data" method.

```py
def validate(self, data):
    exclude_fields = self.context.get('exclude_fields', [])
    for field in exclude_fields:
        # providing a default prevents a KeyError
        # if the field does not exist
        data.pop(field, default=None)

    return data
```

[DRF official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)